# csv ,ssis,flat file source editor

Tags: csv, ssis

I have a flat file source editor for CSV file.
In the flat file connection manager, I can see the whole rows are visible in the preview section of the connection manager but when I am running the package ,finds that it picks only subset of rows from the csv file flat file source editor.Flat file source editor is not picking the whole data.
Why not picking all rows and only subset of rows...
Thanks,
Priyanka Singh

Comment: How do you know it's only picking a subset?

Comment: it can be the condition you have updated connection manager and not redressed  file source